# textEmbed error about sentencepiece for Deberta

Tags: r, r-text

I get error when running deberta in the R-package text, when running:

```
textEmbed(“hello”, model = “microsoft/deberta-v3-base”)
```

error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: This tokenizer cannot be instantiated. Please make sure you have `sentencepiece` installed in order to use this tokenizer.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to get this to work you need to install `sentencepiece` in your conda environment. (And when I did that I had some problems that RStudio was freezing for me – so after updating RStudio and R, I created a specific conda environment with `scipy 1.6` and `sentencepiece`, and then it works without any problems:

```
text::textrpp_install(rpp_version=c("torch==1.8", "transformers==4.12.5",
                                    "numpy", "nltk",
                                    "scipy==1.6", "sentencepiece"),
                      envname = "textrpp_condaenv_sentencepiece")

text::textrpp_initialize(condaenv = "textrpp_condaenv_sentencepiece",
                         refresh_settings = TRUE)
```